# Submit form using Ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax, contacts

I'm a new enthusiast coder specializing in front end. Can someone please help with the back end code.

I want to use Ajax to receive a success message in the modal where the submit and close buttons are after the form has been submitted?

Also, any help with form security would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
 <!--Modal Contact Form-->

 <div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="form-horizontal" action="process.php" method="post" name="contact_form">

        <div class="modal-header">
         <h3>Contact</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input name="contact" type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="Full Name">
               </div>
              </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email:</label>
             <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="you@example.com">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="contact-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message:</label>
             <div class="col-lg-10">
              <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</a>
             <button style="background-color: grey;" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 </div>

 <!--End Contact Modal-->
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'New Message';

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $email);
echo "your message has been submitted .. Thanks you";

?>
```

Comment: AJAX is pretty much all JavaScript (made a lot easier with the jQuery library).  What Javascript have you written so far?

Comment: IMO there's a lot of ajax example in SO. Try to search them

Comment: @DanGoodspeed I actually haven't written a lot of javaScript :( I've only been learning for six months or so on Treehouse. I know I still have so much to learn but I find it really enjoyable! This is a site I have been working on using the Greyscale theme from start bootstrap. http://kararaina.com

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DrixsonOseña I must seem like a complete novice :(

Answer (score 0):

Put a success method to response.

`$array = array( "success" => true, "message" => "your message has been submitted .. Thanks you" );
echo json_decode($array);`

From the ajax request response you can check id success is true and then close your modal.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: { id : menuId },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    if( response.success) {
      // DO YOUR STUFF
    }
  }
});
```

[jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getHttpRequest()
    {
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xmlhttp;
    }
    function executeAction()
    {
    var contact=document.forms["contact_form"]["contact-name"].value;
    var email=document.forms["contact_form"]["contact-email"].value;
    var message=document.forms["contact_form"]["message"].value;
    var xmlhttp; 
    if (email=="")
      {
      document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "Please type the email id!";
                return;
      }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {   
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
                    document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }  
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "sendMail.php?contact="+contact+"&email="+email+"&message="+message, true);

    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="form-horizontal" action="#" method="POST" name="contact_form">

        <div class="modal-header">
         <h3>Contact</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input name="contact" type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="Full Name">
               </div>
              </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email:</label>
             <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="you@example.com">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="contact-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message:</label>
             <div class="col-lg-10">
              <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</a>
             <button style="background-color: grey;" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick="executeAction()">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 </div>

<div id="alert"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

sendMail.php

```
<?php
$contact=$_GET["contact"];

$email = $_GET['email'];
$message = $_GET['message'];
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'New Message';

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $email);
echo "your message has been submitted .. Thanks you";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like either response so far.  Here's what you should do (hopefully it works because I'm not actually testing the code):

1) Add an ID to the form tag.  Let's match the name, so just add the attribute in...

```
id="contact_form"
```

2) Add jQuery and Javascript to the bottom of your HTML page.  This code should go right above the body closing tag.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#contact_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // to stop the form from being submitted normally
    var $this = $(this);  // cache the form
    $this.post($this.attr("action"),$this.serialize(),function(data) {
      alert(data);
      $("#contact").fadeOut();
    });
  });
</script>
```

And that should do it.  Very basic.  Security should be done in the PHP code.

Comment: Can you put the sample page online someplace so we can see it?

Comment: Yes, go to kararaina.com :) This is the page I am trying to fix :)

Comment: I see you made the id of the contact form "ajax-contact"... which is fine other than I told you to name it "contact_form" and gave you the code for that.  If you want to change $("#contact_form") to $("#ajax-contact") to work with the id you chose, you can try that.